# undefined method `invalid_element_errors' in capybara-webkit

Tags: javascript, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

first off I'd like to point out that I'm a bit new at this and thus hope this post will be understandable.

```
Gems:
  rails (2.3.11
  nokogiri (1.5.4)
  cucumber (1.1.9)
  capybara (1.1.2)
  copybara-webkit (0.12.1)
```

Right now I'm doing a project were I'm trying to use cucumber for integration testing of a rails web application.
Since the web-application relies heavily on javascript and ajax I want to use a capybara driver that can handle this. (I just realized :rake_test does not) But I don't want to have a browser window pop up all the time as that will take time.
So I opted on capybara-webkit.
But now that I changed driver, by setting the javascript driver for capybara in my env.rb, I keep getting a annoying error all the time:

```
    undefined method `invalid_element_errors' for #<Capybara::Driver::Webkit:0x9c50bf8> (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/some_steps.rb:37
```

My code at that line:

```
    >> 35  select("something", :from => find("select[class='class_name']")[:id])
    >> 36  click_link('javascript_link')
    >> 37  click_link('another_javascript_link')
```

I'm using a find in line 35 since the id is dynamic.
Now it seems like the problem is actually the find method since if I add another find with known id above this point I'm getting the same error thrown on me on that line instead.

How do I get rid of this problem so I can use capybara-webkit?
I've heard somewhere that this is a problem in the actual driver and that a fix is available  at the github masterbranch and that you somehow can link your gem there?
If so can anybody explain how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've suffered this problem too. It's a capybara-webkit bug: the 0.12.1 version does not have the invalid_element_errors method.

There was a pull request a few months ago with the fix, but it wasn't merged (https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/pull/288). Now they have added the method in the master branch, so you have to use the git repository:

```
gem 'capybara-webkit', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit'
```

Try it and see if it works for you :).